# Prove that $Df(x)x = kf(x)$ implies that the function $f$ is homogenous of degree $k$, i.e., $f(tx) = t^kf(x)$ for all $t > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

**Problem**:

We say $f: R^n - \{ 0\} \rightarrow R$ is *homogenous* of degree $k$ if $f(tx) = t^k f(x)$ for all $t > 0$. Prove that $f$ is homogenous of degree $k$ if and only if $Df(x)x = kf(x)$ for all nonzero **x** $\in R^n$. (Hint: fix **x** and consider $h(t) = t^{-k}f(tx$).)

**Explanation:**

This problem is from the book *Multivariable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds* and my question is concerned with the proof of the second implication $Df(x)x = kf(x)$ implies that the function $f$ is homogenous of degree $k$, i.e., $f(tx) = t^kf(x)$ for all $t > 0$.

**My Proof**:

$h'(t) = t^{-k}Df(tx)x - kt^{-(k+1)}f(tx)$

I would like to use the fact that $Df(x)x = kf(x)$, so since $t^{-k} = t^{-k-1}t$ $\hspace{0.1cm}$we have:

$h'(t) = t^{-(k + 1)}Df(tx)tx - kt^{-(k+1)}f(tx) = t^{-(k + 1)}kf(tx) - kt^{-(k+1)}f(tx) = 0$

Therefore $h(t)$ is a constant function.

My question is how to deduce that since $h(t)$ is a constant function it must be that $f(tx) = t^kf(x)$? taking $f(tx) = t^kf(x)$ would cause $h(t)$ to be constant but is that the only way for it to be constant?

is there a way to directly prove that $f(tx) = t^kf(x)$?

Comment: $h$ is constant on $(0,\infty)$, so for all $t\in (0,\infty)$, we have $h(t)=h(1)$. What does this equation say in terms of $f$ and $t$?

Comment: The hypothesis "$f$ is differentiable" is missing in the statement.

Comment: Choose your preferred [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Proof+Euler+homogeneous).

Comment: I see it says that $t^{-k}f(tx) = f(x)$ so $f(tx) = f(x)t^k$ thank you. @peek-a-boo